# What is the difference between Homogeneous data and Heterogeneous data?

Tags: sql

I really don't understand it could be easier if I find an example. I've searched and I didn't find exactly.
(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 4):

A general example...

```
Homogeneous: Red, Green, Purple

Heterogeneous: White, 1/2/2015, 424291.23
```

To give a specific answer, we'd need to know the context in which you are interested.

Comment: I need it in Database. I have a MySQL database and I want to know if It can be converted to CodernityDB(or something that works faster)

Comment: @Puncte - I would ask that as a separate question. It depends on more than what you've asked in this question.